# Postgres WHERE two arrays have a non-empty intersection

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I have a table with a column `tags` of type `varchar []`.

I would like to select all rows where the tags contains at least one of a set of values.

Something like this:

```sql
-- Not real code
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE non_empty(set_intersection(tags, '{ "apples", "bananas", "cherries" }'))
```

What is the syntax for this?

---

I know I can do a series of `OR`s but that seems less elegant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `&&`, the array overlap operator:

```
select *
from foo
where tags && ARRAY['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries']
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

> `&&`: overlap (have elements in common)